# Awk one liners into script

Tags: shell, awk

I got some one liners in awk. How can i figure this three line into a script?

```
awk -F":|," 'FNR==NR && /INFO  - AId:/ {a[$6$8]=$0;next} END {for (i in a) print i "|" a[i]}' log >t1
awk  '/<?xml version/ {f=1} /<\/iSig>/ {f=0;print $0 "\n" } f' log  >t2
awk -F\| 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} FNR==1 {RS="\n\n"} { for (i in a) {if ($0~i) {print a[i] $0 > i".log";close(i".log")}}}'  t1 t2
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I figure this three line into a script?

By learning `awk`! The best place to start is by reading **[Effective Awk Programming](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat > myscript.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
awk -F":|," 'FNR==NR && /INFO  - AId:/ {a[$6$8]=$0;next} END {for (i in a) print i "|" a[i]}' log > $1
awk  '/<?xml version/ {f=1} /<\/iSig>/ {f=0;print $0 "\n" } f' log  >$2
awk -F\| 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} FNR==1 {RS="\n\n"} { for (i in a) {if ($0~i) {print a[i] $0 > i".log";close(i".log")}}}'  $1 $2
EOF
$ chmod +x myscript.sh
$ ./myscript.sh file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

First as bash you could do it like this:

```
awk -F\| 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} FNR==1 {RS="\n\n"} { for (i in a) {if ($0~i) {print a[i] $0 > i".log";close(i".log")}}}' <(awk -F":|," 'FNR==NR && /INFO  - AId:/ {a[$6$8]=$0;next} END {for (i in a) print i "|" a[i]}' log) <(awk  '/<?xml version/ {f=1} /<\/iSig>/ {f=0;print $0 "\n" } f' log)
```